# Whats wrong with my top down knapsack dp approach?

Tags: data-structures, knapsack-problem

I am not able to figure out what is wrong with my top down knapsack dp approach, its failing testcases on below link, need help.

Question link: https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/0-1-knapsack/

Here is my code:

```
  int fin(int i,int wt,int curprofit,vector<int>&A,vector<int>&B,int C,int n,vector<vector<int>>&dp)
    {
        if(i==n)
            return curprofit;
        if(dp[i][wt]!=-1)
        return dp[i][wt];
        int ret=0;
        ret=max(ret,fin(i+1,wt,curprofit,A,B,C,n,dp));
        if(wt+B[i]<=C)
        {
            ret=max(ret,fin(i+1,wt+B[i],curprofit+A[i],A,B,C,n,dp));
        }
        return dp[i][wt]= ret;
    }
    int Solution::solve(vector<int> &A, vector<int> &B, int C) {
        int n=A.size();
        vector<vector<int>>dp(n+1,vector<int>(C+1,-1));
        return fin(0,0,0,A,B,C,n,dp);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong with it? Is it failing a test case? If so, what is the input and what is the output and what is the expected output?

Comment: Hi @Welbog , yes its failing the testcase, the the testcase is little big I am not able to copy here, can you please try submitting the code on the link I provided.

Comment: No, that's not how Stack Overflow works. The onus is on the question asker to narrow down the problem to as small a code sample and input sample as possible.

Comment: A= 5, 9, 1, 9, 7     and                                                                                                                                                   
 B= 3, 1, 3, 3, 2      and        
 C=9                                                                                                                                       
    expected ans is 30 and the code is giving 26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fix, but I'd suggest you brush up on your recursion knowledge.

Calculate the max profit on the fly, not passing as the parameter. Otherwise, you'll need to put `curprofit` also in the dp state which will be costly. You may also see the output by removing the dp[][] caching. Just put up a correct recursive solution & memoize it.

```
int fin(int i,int wt,vector<int>&A,vector<int>&B,int C,int n,vector<vector<int>>&dp)
    {
        if(i==n)
            return 0;
        if(dp[i][wt]!=-1)
        return dp[i][wt];
        int ret=0;
        ret=max(ret,fin(i+1,wt,A,B,C,n,dp));
        if(wt+B[i]<=C)
        {
            ret=max(ret,fin(i+1,wt+B[i],A,B,C,n,dp) + A[i]);
        }
        return dp[i][wt]= ret;
    }
    int Solution::solve(vector<int> &A, vector<int> &B, int C) {
        int n=A.size();
        vector<vector<int>>dp(n+1,vector<int>(C+1,-1));
        return fin(0,0,A,B,C,n,dp);
    }
```